# Why does AscW() give a Compile Error in Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do this in Excel VBA:

```
Cells(1, 2) = AscW(Cells(1, 1).Value)
```

It works fine in Excel 12 (2007) and 16 (2016) on one of my machines (Windows 7 laptop), but the machine (Windows thin client, not sure the version but looks a bit like Windows 7) that has Excel 14 (2010) gives "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

Any ideas? Is it the machine, a bug/feature in that version of Excel, or something else?

*Update* It seems to matter which machine the workbook was created on. They are both `.xlsm` files, but the one I created on the laptop works fine when I copy it onto the thin client. The workbook that I created on the thin client (actually, I received from someone else) has the problem. Both have the public sub in the worksheet's VBA code. Sadly I cannot transfer files in the other direction.

Comment: Works for me on Excel 2010 x64.

Comment: Try `Cells(1, 2).value =`

Comment: `AscW` should not be used on Mac.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  _Should not_, but can be (according to the help file).  The code works fine in Excel 2010. What value is in cell A1?  Is it on the Mac?

Comment: Try with a full qualification: `Strings.AscW(Cells(1, 1).Value)`. I would get this error If I were to create a function named `AscW` in a module.

Comment: And just in case the cell is empty: `Strings.AscW(Cells(1, 1).Value & vbNullChar)`

Comment: Some weird regional setting (is there a Birmingham regional setting - cos, you know, it's Brum? :p )  Tried your code exactly as you've entered (except for procedure heading) and it returned 120 in cell B1 for `x`.  Same as if I'd added `=CODE(A1)`.

Comment: Thanks Florent B., can you make that into an answer so I can accept it as the solution? `Strings.AscW` did indeed fix it. Now the mystery is just "why"!

Comment: @PhilHibbs, the fact that it's working could simply be because the VBA was recompiled (It could be a portability issue between 32 and 64 bits Excel). It would be far more interesting to know why this is happening. Though there's no way to confirm without a reproductible example.

Comment: I might be able to create a minimal test case and get permission to transfer it outside of the secure estate.